# Visual studio report System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException when compile using .net native tool chain

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, compiler-errors

My app build and run successfully, without checking the option `Compile with .net navite too chain`.

After I check the option, vs report the errors.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException' in System.Private.Interop.dll
Windows.Foundation.IReference`1<Double>
```

What can I do to successfully run the app?
[image]

Comment: That's interesting, could you share your code or sample that could reproduce this?

Comment: I created a new project, and can't reproduce it. So this issue maybe related to my project,      so I'm going to uncheck the option, until I find a solution, thanks.

Comment: Great, if any updates please post below, if  have found the solution please post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out that it's due to a third party controls called `HN.Controls.ImageEx`. I unreferenced it, my project runs ok.

I'm contacting the author to handle this.